# Android - How to persist on same tab after refresh?

Tags: android, tabs, swiperefreshlayout

I am using tabbed layout in my android application and in it I am giving an option to pull down refresh. but after refreshing it is not being redirected on same tab.

TabsAdapter code -

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // code
            return new MyFragment(args);
        case 1:
            // code
            return new MyFragment(args);
       case 2:
            // code
            return new MyFragment(args);
        case 3:
            // code
            return new MyFragment(args);
}
```

Redirecting code is as follows -

```
Intent i = MyFragment.this.getActivity().getIntent();
                startActivity(i);
                MyFragment.this.getActivity().finish();
```

How could I redirect my intent to same tab?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `getIntent` method always return the intent that was used to create your activty. So the user action, like switching to another tab after the activity was launch can not be found in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a SharedPreferences to store the last selected tab.

```
selectedtab=tab.getSelectedTabIndex(); // or something else depending on your tab widget
sharedpreference.edit().putInt("selectedtab",selectedtab).apply();
```

then on your onCreate on same class

```
selectedtab=sharedpreference.getInt("selectedtab",0);
tab.setSelectedTabIndex(selectedtab);
```